# How to fix wrong entered time Python?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, time

I have a chatbot that accepts time string from the user like:

```
10:00
8pm
3:45am
4am
```

But sometimes I am getting military time like `22:40pm`.
I want to overcome this issue and not bother the user, please advise how can fix the time?
I am using:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse(time)
```

But I am getting an error it can't parse `22:40pm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `am`/`pm` designation is always wrong (`22:40pm` is somehow less 'wrong' than `22:40am`) when added to times past 12:59, you could do some string slicing, test if the first digits are a possibly invalid time, and then remove the designation at the end if it's there.

But it's easier to *always* remove `am/pm` for times past 12:59, with an appropriate regex:

```
((?<=(?!10|11|12)[12]\d:\d\d))[ap]m
```

This matches `am` and `pm` (to be replaced with an empty string `''`) but only when prefaced with a series of decimals `1\d:\d\d` or `2\d:\d\d` (a total range of `10:00` up to `29:99`). This is a *positive* lookbehind: the pattern inside it *must* appear before the matching pattern `am`/`pm`.

```
 (1)       am or pm
 (2)  <=dd:dd
 (3)  !>10,11,or 12
      22:40am
```

But the first pair of these decimals are *correct* times when they have one of the values `10`, `11`, or `12` (because `10:20am` is simply `10:20`; `10:20pm` is `22:20`; `12:30am` equals `0:30`). Because they are correct there is no need to remove `am` and `pm` and so they are *excluded* from the positive lookbehind by a further *negative lookahead* inside the lookbehind. It is a negative lookahead and so a match means *failure*, not *success*.

([Interactive sample on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Zth1Zc/1))

Full code:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
import re

for time in ['3:40', '3:40am', '3:40pm',
    '03:40', '03:40am', '03:40pm',
    '12:40', '12:40am', '12:40pm',
    '13:40', '13:40am', '13:40pm',
    '22:40', '22:40am', '22:40pm']:
    time = re.sub(r'((?<=(?!10|11|12)[12]\d:\d\d))[ap]m', '', time)
    print (time, parse(time).time())
```

which outputs

```
3:40 03:40:00
3:40am 03:40:00
3:40pm 15:40:00
03:40 03:40:00
03:40am 03:40:00
03:40pm 15:40:00
12:40 12:40:00
12:40am 00:40:00
12:40pm 12:40:00
13:40 13:40:00
13:40 13:40:00
13:40 13:40:00
22:40 22:40:00
22:40 22:40:00
22:40 22:40:00
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation for the regex? @usr2564301